# Where are OS X man pages stored?

Tags: mac-osx

I have installed iftop on Mac OS X 10.7 from source but the installer didn't copy the man page to where it should be. I have no idea where it should be either. Does anyone know where I should cp it to?

I found this thread http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=527075 but as you can see no one actually answers the question.

echo $MANPATH

returns nothing by the way.

Comment: You can pass `--path` to `man` to show the path of a page instead of the page itself, which can quickly reveal where most pages are kept (e.g. `man --path man`). For a more extensive discussion of where man pages can be, read "Search Path For Manual Pages” in [`man`’s man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/man.1.html).

Comment: My previous comment now has a broken link, as Apple appears to removed man pages from their developer library on the web, but just type `man man`  to view the page locally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The man pages on MacOS X are located in `/usr/share/man`.

Checking a nearby system, the $MANPATH variable's contents look like: `/usr/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/X11/share/man`

As for the application you compiled, how did you install the binary? Was this installed from a basic tarball?

Comment: Followed the ./configure && make in the instructions. Thanks for the reply. I had found the answer before I posted my own answer but I had to wait 8 hours cos I'm new.

Answer (score 7):

On **Mac OS X**, the `/private/etc/manpaths` file is the default file that will tell man where to look for manpages.

On my machine, it contains two paths:

`/usr/share/man
/usr/local/share/man`

Comment: Using macOS Big Sur (version 11.5.2) i can confirm `/usr/local/share/man/` is the desired location for storing manuals.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above - the path is `/usr/share/man`

As an option - you can install iftop using `homebrew` - then it will store man pages in `/usr/local/Cellar/iftop/0.17/share/man`

And to specify a right path to man pages during the install from sources - you can pass `--mandir=` parameter to `./configure` script

i.e. something like

`./configure --disable-debug --prefix=/usr/local --mandir=/usr/share//man`
and then do `make install`

Answer (score 1):

I found a link to someone writing a script to convert man pages to pdf so they could read them on their iPad.

The location of man pages on OS X is:

/usr/share/man/

Answer (score 1):

Another location (especially section 2 of the manpages) is:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man/.